# Is it possible to configure FxCop 10 to use a .csproj as its target?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, fxcop

I would like to configure FxCop (10) to run against the assembly produced by a .csproj in Visual Studio 2010 (Professional Edition). As I am sure most people will know, the assembly is typically placed in Release and Debug directories, so pointing directly at the .dll produced is not ideal.

In addition, I would like to run analysis against an assembly that has several dependencies, but do not want to analyze those .dlls (some of which are GAC-installed).

I'm looking for how to do this under vs2010, with fxcop10.

Comment: It is unclear what edition of VS2010 you are using.  Look for the Analyze toplevel menu item, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to configure FxCop (10) to run against the assembly
>   produced by a .csproj in Visual Studio 2010.

That's not really possible out-of-the-box with the stand-alone FxCop UI.  If you're willing to forgo the rich UI and run within Visual Studio, you could [run FxCop from a post-build event](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2007/02/24/faq-how-do-i-run-fxcop-during-a-post-build-event.aspx), which will result in executing it over the assemblies produced by your current build configuration.

> In addition, I would like to run analysis against an assembly that has
>   several dependencies, but do not want to analyze those .dlls (some of
>   which are GAC-installed).

FxCop needs information from referenced assemblies for certain rules.  A given target assembly cannot be analyzed properly unless its references can be loaded by FxCop.  However, there's nothing forcing you to load them from the GAC.  You can control the locations in which FxCop will look for referenced assemblies either via a .fxcop project or via fxcopcmd.exe command line arguments.